# prevent autoClosingBrackets when inserting content as result of registerCompletionItemProvider

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

VSCode extension development offers a way to contribute to the auto-completion providers aka *InttelliSense*.
It is possible to complete inputs as the following snippet shows.
However, when implementing the snippet below (just as an example), it will watch AsciiDoc files for the `:` (colon) sign input. Once the sign has been entered, the autocompletion provider is executed.
In the example below, it will complete with a selected items label surrounded by curly braches.
E.g. selecting `foo` should result in `{foo}`.
But there is a problem with this approach: Once the completion item has been selected, the default VSCode behaviour for the `"editor.autoClosingBrackets"` setting fires. This will cause -as the inserted string starts with a curly bracket - that the an additional curly bracket is added afterwards. So the result will be `{foo}}` instead of `{foo}` with the cursor placed between the last two curly brackets (`{foo}|}`).

```
const disposable = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
    {
      language: "asciidoc",
      scheme: "file",
    },
    AsciidocProvider,
    ...[":"]
  );

  export const AsciidocProvider = {
    provideCompletionItems,
  };

  export async function provideCompletionItems(
    document: vscode.TextDocument,
    position: vscode.Position
  ): Promise<vscode.CompletionItem[]> {
    return Promise.resolve([
      {
        label: `{${label}}`,
        kind: vscode.CompletionItemKind.Variable,
        sortText: `a_${label}`,
        insertText: `{${label}}` // <-- additional "}" will be added as result of the "editor.autoClosingBrackets" setting
      }
    ])
  }
```

I thought I can handle this by checking the configuration for `"editor.autoClosingBrackets"`. If it is configured as `never`, add the closing bracket manually. If not: let the auto completion do the rest.
But this will lead into another problem: The cursor is placed at the wrong position (right before the last curly bracket, e.g. `{foo|}`). This behaviour doesn't allow a user to keep on writing a path right after a completion item has been selected.

**Context:**

In AsciiDoc it's possible to define somewhere in  the document variables that can contain for example a path string. My goal is to provide such variables as completion items and keep on writing the path target after the variable is inserted.

The current detailed feature implementation for this can be found here:

See PR here: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-vscode/pull/381

So my question is:
Is there a way to tell VSCode not to run `"editor.autoClosingBrackets"` when the `registerCompletionItemProvider` is executed?

Comment: It looks like the question author has since opened an issue on the VSCode repo: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111764